# LINQ to SQL - The query contains references to items defined on a different data context.'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is the function that keeps flagging. I know its only one context.  I have a context with 3 tables that I am joining together and trying to take a SELECT and input it into my Patient Class.

Just learning LINQ so trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

```
public static List<Patient> getPatients()
            {
                List<Patient> cl = new List<Patient>();
                DbSub db = new DbSub();
                var query = (from a in db.Sig().Clients
                             join b in db.Sig().Encounters
                             on a.client_id equals b.client_id
                             join c in db.Sig().client_programs
                             on b.enco_id equals c.enco_id
                             orderby a.med_rec_no
                             select new Patient()
                             {
                                 med_rec_no = a.med_rec_no,
                                 client_id = a.client_id
                             }).ToList();
                return query;
```

Oh and here is the helper methods.

```
public class DbSub
        {
          public DataClasses1DataContext SigBHDS()
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(SqlHelper.CnnVal("SigBHDS"));
                return db;
            }
          public SDB Sig()
            {
                SDB db = new SDB(SqlHelper.CnnVal("S"));
                return db;
            }
        }


        public static class SqlHelper
        {
            public static string CnnVal(string name)
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
            }
        }


public class Patient
{
    public string med_rec_no { get; set; }
    public int client_id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to use one context? `var context = db.Sig(); var query = from a in context.Clients join b in context.Encounters`

Comment: If you're just learning, you should probably be learning EF instead, as it's more popular and still under active development.

Comment: You are awesome, Doing the var context = db.Sig(); worked great.  One thing to add is I put it inside of a using statement for instant disposable.   Now David Browne..... What is EF?

Comment: @GarenBarnett LINQ to SQL's replacement